# Issue with complex manipulation operation on maps

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Say I have the following two maps:

```
Map<Member, List<Message>> one = ...;//one constructed somehow
Map<Member, List<Message>> two = ...;//two also constructed somehow
```

I would like to obtain a third map containing the content of **one** and **two**.

So if a member key is in both one and two, the list value from the entry in two will be added to the list value from the entry in one.

What is the best and cleanest way to achieve this possibly using java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the merge method.

```
Map<Member, List<Message>> third = new HashMap<>(one);
two.forEach((k, v) -> third.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> {v1.addAll(v2); return v1;}));
```

This will also modify the list in the map `one` since you're manipulating the same reference. If you don't want, i.e create a new list, you can do it like this:

```
Map<Member, List<Message>> third = new HashMap<>(one);
two.forEach((k, v) -> third.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream()).collect(toList())));
```

The merged list will be a new list but be careful that this won't be the case for the keys which weren't in both maps. You'd need to deep copy all the lists to achieve this.

Just added another solution with the Stream API:

```
Map<Member, List<Message>> third = Stream.of(one, two)
                                         .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                                         .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                        Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                        (l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(toList())));
```

I also added my contribution to the [proton-pack library](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack). With this you could also achieve it like this:

```
Map<Member, List<Message>> third = MapStream.ofMaps(one, two)
                                            .mergeKeys((l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(toList()))
                                            .collect();
```